# Finding events within a given timeframe with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My brain must be completely mush at the moment because I'm stuck on this.  I have a table with dates that someone was given a drug and this comes with the amount of days that they are to take the drug.  A person can be prescribed `n` number of drugs so the CTE of the following query is to find the largest timeframe(the fill date of the drug + the days supply.)  I would then like to find the people that were on at least seven different drugs at the same time.  I'm having trouble finding the drugs the people are on for a given timeframe.  This needs to be restricted to the time period for which a person was on at least `seven` drugs at once.  Everything works fine up until that last part.

sample data from the CTE  (fillDate + longestscript = endingDate)

[image]

concurrent scripts is determined by `count(distinct rx.drugname)` in the query

[image]

```
  ;with cte 
as
(
      select rx.patid
        ,rx.fillDate
        ,MAX(rx.dayssup) as longestScript
        ,DATEADD(day,cast(rx.dayssup as int),rx.filldate) as endingDate
        from rx
        group by rx.patid, rx.fillDate,rx.daysSup
 ),
 startends as (
         select patid, FillDate as thedate, 1 as isstart 0 as isend
         from CTE union all
         select patid, EndingDate as thedate, 0 as isstart, 1 as isend
         from CTE
     ),
     cums as (
         select se.*,
                (select min(thedate) from startends se2 where se2.filledate > se.filldate) as nextdate,
                (select SUM(isstart) from startends se2 where se2.filldate <= se.filldate) as cumstarts,
                (select SUM(isend) from startends se2 where se2.filldate <= se.filldate) as cumends
         from startends se
     )
select *
from cums
where sumstarts - cumends >= 7
```

You can see in the second query each patient appears many times with a different span of time between fillDate and endingDate.  How can I write a query to get the nine drugs repeated for the first row of the second screen cap?  SQL Server 08 r2 is my dbms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure of your schema, so am guessing slightly, however the first thing I have notices is that in your CTE `x`, you are selecting `MAX(DaysSup)` but also grouping by `dayssup`, making the max redundant.

However, I don't really think this is relevant to your problem. I would personally take a different approach to solving this. I am assuming you have a table along the lines of:

```
CREATE TABLE rx
(       PatID           INT,
        FillDate        DATE,
        Dayssup         INT,
        DrugName        VARCHAR(50)
)
```

So you can do something along the lines of:

```
SELECT  rx.PatID,
        rx.FillDate,
        rx.DrugName,
        [DateTaken] = DATEADD(DAY, v.Number, FillDate)
FROM    RX
        INNER JOIN master..spt_values v
            ON v.Number BETWEEN 0 AND rx.DaysSup
            AND v.Type = 'P'
```

This will give a list of all the dates a drug has been taken by each patient, rather than a range, so you can then use something like:

```
WITH x AS
(   SELECT  rx.PatID,
            rx.FillDate,
            rx.DrugName,
            [DateTaken] = DATEADD(DAY, v.Number, FillDate) 
    FROM    rx
            INNER JOIN master..spt_values v
                ON v.Number BETWEEN 0 AND rx.DaysSup
                AND v.Type = 'P'
), y AS
(   SELECT  x.PatID,
            x.DateTaken,
            DrugsTaken = COUNT(DISTINCT x.DrugName)
    FROM    x
    GROUP BY x.PatID, x.DateTaken
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT x.DrugName) >= 7
), z AS
(   SELECT  *,
            GroupID = DATEDIFF(DAY, - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PatID ORDER BY DateTaken DESC), DateTaken)
    FROM    y
)
SELECT  z.PatID, 
        [MostConccurent] = MAX(z.DrugsTaken),
        [DateStarted] = MIN(z.DateTaken),
        [DateEnded] = MAX(z.DateTaken)
FROM    z
GROUP BY z.PatID, z.GroupID;
```

The first part I have covered, the second part simply limits the results to all dates with 7 or more drugs. The third CTE groups each patient by consecutive dates, and the last gets the min and max for each of those dates.

If you need a list of the drugs taken on each of those dates you can then join back to the cte `x`:

```
SELECT  z.PatID, 
        x.DrugName,
        [MostConccurent] = MAX(z.DrugsTaken),
        [DateStarted] = MIN(z.DateTaken),
        [DateEnded] = MAX(z.DateTaken)
FROM    z
        INNER JOIN x
            ON x.PatID = z.PatID
            AND x.DateTaken = z.DateTaken
GROUP BY z.PatID, z.GroupID, x.DrugName;
```

Answer (score 2):

By any chance, are you using SQL Server 2012?  The solution is *much* simpler in that database, because Microsoft extended the window functions to include partial sums.

The idea is to calculate the number of cumulative fills and ends on each possible date -- whether a fill date or end date.  Then the difference is the number of cumulative scripts.  The following gives the information for each date:

```
with cte as (<your query>),
     startends as (
         select patid, FillDate as thedate, 1 as isstart 0 as isend
         from CTE union all
         select patid, EndingDate as thedate, 0 as isstart, 1 as isend
         from CTE
     ),
     cums as (
         select se.*,
                (select min(thedate) from startends se2 where se2.filledate > se.filldate) as nextdate,
                (select SUM(isstart) from startends se2 where se2.filldate <= se.filldate) as cumstarts,
                (select SUM(isend) from startends se2 where se2.filldate <= se.filldate) as cumends
         from startends se
     )
select *
from cums
where cumstarts - cumends >= 7
```

Each row in the result set has a "nextdate" which defines the period of time for which the condition holds.  You will probably end up with multiple records for one period, as patients go from 7 to 8 to 9 to 8 to 9 to 7 concurrent prescriptions.

If you have a lot of data, this will be a rather inefficient query, because it is doing rather expensive join operations.  As I say, though, this would be quite efficient in SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Hopefully you don't have too much data.  If you have millions of records, this might take a while to return.

Comment: It returns about 80k or so.  I'm always looking out for performance issues, but I'm the only person who deals with this particular database so a 45 second query isn't all that bad :).

Comment: I'm not familiar with using multiple CTEs at once so it might be me, but when I try to put that query into SSMS I get a host of errors.

Comment: can you take a look at the updated query.  I'm getting lots of squiggly lines saying line 12 and line 16 'invalid column names'